# Transcription in Google Translate API

Tags: google-translate

Is it possible to get transcription of word translated by Google API?

Same as in translate.google.com right under the textarea.

I need translation and transcription of single words only, like in dictionary, so may be Google offers some dictionary API, simpler than translation but with transcription?

Look at this picture, second red arrow points to transcription of word "transcription"

[image: second red arrow points to transcription of word " transcription"]

Comment: Can you give an example please? Google Translate uses https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/ to translate a word or a phrase. What do you mean for "transcription" and not translation?

Comment: I updated question, look at pic pls. I need dictionary functionality, to be able to get variants of translation of single word, not sentences, and i need transcriptions of this translations, to show user how to say this word correctly.

Comment: Ok, I've understood. Google Translation API doesn't give you the variants of translation of a single word and doesn't give to you the text to speech functionality.
Translate API can detect the language automatically and respond the translated text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Translation API doesn't give you the variants of translation of a single word and doesn't give to you the text to speech functionality. Translate API can detect the language automatically and respond the translated text.

Comment: Too  bad. Do you know any legal way to reproduce functionality of translate. google.com I need?

Comment: For speech to text you can use HTML native components, for the transcription one, i don't know, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

2023. 

[Dictionary API](https://dictionaryapi.dev/) provides word's phonetic transcription along with a lot of other useful information.